# Set Outlook 2007 to not have a due date for tasks by default

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, tasks

I use Tasks in Outlook 2007 and I like to enter new tasks using the textbox in the To-Do Bar (ie. without actually opening a new Task window). This automatically sets today's date as the due date for the new task, which is unhelpful in most cases. Most of my tasks don't have a specific due date, but from the next day on the task appears in red, distracting my attention from the few tasks that really are overdue. I then have to open the Task and manually clear its due date. Is there any way I can set the default due date to "none" for tasks that I enter from the To-Do bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to your tasks
- Right click the flag on a task
- Click "Select Quick Picks"
- Change the selection to "None" or "No Due Date"

Future quick checks will not have a due date.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! That does exactly what I want, though the menu item is called "Set Quick Click" for me.